# Self join to get the records from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, self-join

Lets say I have a table A with 2 columns userid and email

```
userid      email
abc         coMmon@email.com
xyz         common@email.com
```

I would like have result as

`abc,xyz, common@email.com`

I wrote a query as below

`select old1.userid, new1.userid, old1.email
from A old1
LEFT JOIN A new1
ON old1.email = new1.email`

But this gives me the result as
`abc , abc, common@email.com`

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: You want one column `abc, xyz`?

Comment: I need these in two different column.

Comment: Ok, thanks for conforming `left join` mandatory?

Comment: left join not mandatory.

Comment: just to update, My query is working the issue was with case, as orcale is case sensitive I was not getting expected result, now I use the upper function and it starts working. Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

You want `listagg()`:

```
select listagg(userid, ',') within group (order by userid) as userids,
       email
from a
group by email;
```

I see no reason to add another comma at the end of `userids`, but you can use `|| ','` if you really want one.

I realize that `,` might be a *column* separator and not a comma in a string.  If you want pairs of userids in separate columns, then you can use a self-join

```
select a1.userid, a2.userid, a1.email
from a a1 join
     a a2
     on a1.email = a2.email and a1.userid < a2.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say *old* and *new* it means chronological order. You need some column which determines order, now we don't know if `abc` is older than `xyz`. If you have such column (let's say `seq`) you can use it in your query to find *previous* value. You can make self-join or better use `lag()` function:

```
select lag(userid) over (partition by email order by seq) prev_userid, userid, email 
  from a
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a5f080d5f6c0d9a2da86074b61c03523)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

As per your expected output maybe it helps you.

Please check this

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    userid varchar(20),
    email varchar(30)
);
INSERT INTO @table VALUES('abc','common@email.com'),('xyz','common@email.com')

SELECT a1.userid AS UserID1,a2.userid AS UserID2, a1.email
FROM @table a1 
JOIN @table a2
     on a1.email = a2.email and a1.userid < a2.userid;
```

> 1. Select Query Output

[image]

```
SELECT CONCAT(a1.userid,',',a2.userid) AS userid, a1.email
FROM @table a1 
JOIN @table a2
     on a1.email = a2.email and a1.userid < a2.userid;
```

> 2. Select Query Output

[image]

```
SELECT CONCAT(a1.userid,',',a2.userid,', ',a1.email) AS Result
FROM @table a1 
JOIN @table a2
     ON a1.email = a2.email and a1.userid < a2.userid;
```

> 3. Select Query output

[image]